# Unable to DOM innerHTML of a div, presumably because browser has to click certain buttons for elements to appear

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing a program that pulls articles off a wiki. In order to obtain the page source, you must click two buttons. I've gotten puppeteer to click these buttons, however trying to DOM the innerHTML of the element that appears after clicking these buttons returns an error:

```
 Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

This is the code I'm using and this is the HTML I'm trying to DOM:

```
 (async () => {
 if (once == false) {
     browser = await puppeteer.launch({
         headless: false,
         ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
     });
     wiki = await browser.newPage();
     once = true;
     console.log("Once")
 }
 await wiki.goto(link);
 
 await wiki.click("#more-options-button"),
  
 await wiki.click("#view-source-button"),
    
 pageText = await wiki.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#action-area > div").innerHTML)

 console.log(pageText);

 })();
```

---

## HTML:

[image]

I'm assuming this is because I have to click the buttons for the text to appear. Trying

```
document.querySelector("#action-area > div").innerHTML
```

Works in the browser but not with puppeteer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if the element is available indeed go to the Chrome console and type `$('#action-area > div').innerHTML`. If it gives back the expected result then you will know your selector is correct and your element is already available (doesn't require further clicks).

The following format should work, you can put a `page.waitForSelector()` before the evaluate:

```js
await wiki.waitForSelector("#action-area > div");
const pageText = await wiki.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await wiki.$("#action-area > div"));
```

*FYI:* the `await wiki.click("..."),` lines should be ended by either a semicolon or just semicolonless to terminate properly the script, but not with a comma!

Comment: This solved the problem! And whoops, you're right, I didn't see that, those lines were previously parameterized in a function I removed and I forgot to change them, thanks for pointing it out.